# How can we set laravel eloquent relations in mongo db?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I have two collections `user` & `booking`. I need to fetch some fields from user collection `( usrFirstname, usrLastname, usrEmail)` and all fields from booking collection. I tried some eloquent model relation but I am getting some error.

`user    -> _id, usrFirstname, usrLastname, usrEmail, usrPhone, usrMobile`

`booking -> _id, booking_number, booking_date, user`

`booking.user` is related with the `_id` of `user` collection.

I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package.

**Booking.php (Eloquent Model)**

```
public function user()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
```

**BookingController.php**

```
$books = Booking::all();
foreach ($books as $book) {
   echo $book->user->usrFirstname;
}
```

**Error**

`FatalThrowableError in Builder.php line 1654:
Call to a member function compileSelect() on null`

[image: Detailed error message]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this package in order to work with eloquent and mongo
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

> If u use "jenssegers/laravel-mongodb" add "HybridRelations" to your model with "MySql|MariaDB" connection.

[image]